# overriding tostring method in Gregorian Calendar

Tags: java

using inner class, i'm overriding toString method of Gregorian Calendar:

```
 GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 5, 12)
      {
          public String toString()
          {
              return String.format("%s/%s/%s", YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH);
          }
      };
```

when i print date it should be something like this:

2010/5/12

but the output is:

1/2/5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY_OF_MONTH` are just field numbers to use in `get` and `set` methods. This is how it works

```
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%d/%02d/%02d", get(YEAR), get(MONTH) + 1, get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
```

note that month in Calendar starts with 0, this is why we need `get(MONTH) + 1`

Answer (score 7):

This should give you what you are expecting:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 5, 12)
        {
            public String toString()
            {
                Date thisDate = this.getTime();
                return sdf.format(thisDate);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there.. but the YEAR, MONTH are referring to enums, and what you are printing is the ordinal of those enums. What you want is to get the real value using those enums with the GregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.Value).

Example

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 5, 12)
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s/%s/%s", get(YEAR), get(MONTH)+1, get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
};
```

that will fix your problems.